# Declaring 2D vector in constructor

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I want my class to contain a 2D vector array in the form:

```
vector<vector<Node> > Grid(20, vector<Node>(20));
```

When I try and access it from a member function like so:

```
Grid[10][10]
```

I get the error:

```
expression must have pointer-to-object type
```

If I declare the 2D vector inside the member function it works perfectly. What do I have to do, to have it in the constructor?

Comment: I assume you are not trying to *declare* something inside a constructor and use it in a member function. You need to declare in the class and initialize in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class X
{
public:
    X();
    vector<vector<Node> > Grid;
};

X::X()
    :Grid(20, vector<Node>(20))
{
}
```