# Trying to create a 2D array of a template class with unknown size (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

I have a class with member variable:

```
T** board
```

This is supposed to represent cells on a game board, where each cell is of type `T` which is an abstract class. The size of the board is determined at runtime (hence the pointer and not the array declaration).

In the constructor of the same class, I attempt to initialize the arrays that make up the board:

```
template<class T, class J, const int X, const int Y>
Gameboard<T,J,X,Y>::Gameboard() {
    board = new T[X];
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        board[i] = new T[Y];
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:17:
./Gameboard.h:40:17: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Tile'
    board = new T[X];
In file included from main.cpp:17:
./Gameboard.h:42:24: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Tile'
        board[i] = new T[Y];
```

How should I be doing this to properly create a 2D array?

Comment: You should be making a `vector<vector<T>>`, then you can size it in your constructor [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456919/declaring-2d-vector-in-constructor)

Comment: @Cyber if it's a rectangular grid, just vector<T> with coordinate transformation will be better.

Comment: @Cubic That is also a good option.

Comment: @Cyber, I thought of that before, but figured it was safer to use arrays because I can set a max value and be sure nothing goes past the boundaries of my board.

Comment: @maxmackie And what makes you think you can't do that with `vector`?

Comment: The only configuration of words that form a sentence with array and safer in them, is "don't use arrays, use a safer wrapper around them (like vector) instead"

Comment: @maxmackie, how about using `std::array` if you want the size to be fixed? You can pass in the template parameters to specify the size.

Comment: @Cyber, my googling seemed to show me I couldn't put a hard limit on the size of a vector.

Comment: @Cyber, if using `std::vector<std::vector<T>> board` instead, would the constructor need to initialize anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the approach I would take is to make a 2D `std::vector`. If you really want to make sure that the lengths are fixed at compile time then you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for this:

```
#include <array>
template<class T, class J, const int X, const int Y>
class Gameboard{

std::array< std::array<T, Y>, X> board;
}
```

This should default initialize all the elements. If this doesn't do what you want then you can write your own initialization fairly easily if you need.

Comment: just being pedantic, `Y` should be the inner parameter and `X` the outer, if you want syntax like `T[X][Y]`

Comment: I'm starting to think I should use `std::vector`. If I change `board` to be `std::vector<std::vector<T>> board`, then what should the initialization look like? I'm getting errors doing `board = new std::vector<std::vector<T>>` and then looping over `X` to push new vectors to the main one.

Comment: @maxmackie, treat `std::vector` as a value type and don't use `new`.

Comment: @maxmackie if you use `std::vector` then you don't need any more `new`. Just use `push_back` to push elements into the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate first memory for the array of `X` pointers-to-T,

```
board = new T* [X];
```

instead of what you have now `board = new T[X];`

Or, as mentioned in the comments/answers, just use a `std::vector` or `std::array`